# In R enviroment keras installed but not working

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, conda

I recently got intetested in Machine Learning, bougt book about doing ML with R  software and keras library. Unfortunetley I cannot deal with correct setup. Most basic example like:

```
library('keras')

mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

Produce error:

> Error: ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\MachineLearning\conda\envs\r-tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "D:\MachineLearning\conda\envs\r-tensorflow\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 658, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 571, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 922, in
>   create_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   ImportError: DLL load failed: Procedura inicjowania biblioteki doĹ‚Ä…czanej dyn

Also this is the most basic setup. Keras were installed with:

```
install_keras(method = "conda", conda = "D:\\MachineLearning\\conda\\Scripts\\conda.exe" )
```

I think something is going wrong in Python layer. Also I read posts with similar problems described in which the cause were missing library MSVCP140.DLL, but I have it in System32, detectable from %PATH%.
Any ideas?